# Make NaN white with mapshow MatLab

Tags: matlab, colors, mapping, nan

I am using mapshow in MatLab but I have some polygons with no data, which I would like to leave blank (i.e. colored white). Right now it shows the default yellow. What can I do?

link to map with NaNs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyr82.png

Reproducible code below,

```
      MapLatLimit = [41 48];
MapLonLimit = [-74 -66];

NEstates = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true, 'BoundingBox', [MapLonLimit' MapLatLimit']);
fall = flipud(bone(numel(NEstates)));
datawithNaN = num2cell([10 20 30 NaN 40 50 NaN NaN]);
    [NEstates.datawithNaN] =  deal(datawithNaN{:});
densityColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon', {'datawithNaN',   [0 50], 'FaceColor', fall});
mapshow(NEstates, 'DisplayType', 'polygon',  'SymbolSpec', densityColors)
```

Comment: If you could include enough code to run, it would be easier to help. Assuming you have some matrix of data containing some NaNs, then you can get a binary mask indicating the locations of all NaNs using the `isnan()` function. You should then be able to assign the color you want at those locations.

Comment: Thanks, please find the new code above, which should run in almost any latest version of MatLab. The NaN are displayed as yellow regions, how can make them white keeping the rest of the colormap for the other regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Treat 'NaN' as a category itself and then assigned a color to it. Code below.

```
      MapLatLimit = [41 48];
MapLonLimit = [-74 -66];

NEstates = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true, 'BoundingBox', [MapLonLimit' MapLatLimit']);
datawithNaN = [30 20 30 NaN 40 50 NaN NaN];
% Here replace NaNs with a number (treat as category):
datawithNaN(isnan(datawithNaN)) = 0;
datawithNaN = num2cell(datawithNaN);

% Here I create a color map, using white for NaN (category = 0);
mycolormap = [  1 1 1;...
               .4 .1 .9;...
               .3 .2 .8;...
               .2 .3 .7;...
               .1 .4 .6];
[NEstates.datawithNaN] =  deal(datawithNaN{:});
densityColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon', {'datawithNaN',   [0 50], 'FaceColor', mycolormap});
mapshow(NEstates, 'DisplayType', 'polygon',  'SymbolSpec', densityColors)
```